# How to Build a Spring Boot REST API with Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

When I try to send any request with the API of this project by path(for example, http://localhost:8082/api/user), the result is always 404Not Found in postman.

why ???

**file.propertise**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = user
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port = 8082
```

**User Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**Repository Classes**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> findAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> findUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(id);

        if(user.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }

    @PostMapping
    public User saveUser(@Validated @RequestBody User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add your curl/postman request to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i understand , you since you are passing a path variable you should try the url with a adding an id that exists in your database , else there is a property that specifies the initial base url for your application when it runs in a server server.servlet.context-path=/api for Spring 2.X versions and spring.data.rest.basePath=/api With Spring Boot 1.2+ (<2.0).
so to avoid redundant "api" in your path your request mapping should be @RequestMapping("/user").
Please let me know if this helped

Comment: I added server.servlet.context-path=/api in a file.properties and edit @RequestMapping("/api/user") to @RequestMapping("/user"). I still have the same problem when I send any request with the API of this project by path(for example, http://localhost:8082/api/user)

Comment: RequestMapping("/user") and have you tried localhost:8082/api/user/anyid ?

Comment: yes, i did that

Comment: can you show me the packages of your application ?

Comment: {
    "timestamp": "2022-10-16T14:43:46.845+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/user/1"
}

Comment: i need details about the packages within your application

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nQz50y9dDUfrmlO1kjDvB_zpbysjQtim/view?usp=sharing

Comment: pom.xml

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xL37fEWYp5TvzR-rTh5neUl-d6tALSrT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: could you change the packages of your entities, controller and repository to com.ResgistrationAndLogin and retry for example com.ResgistrationAndLogin.controllers

Comment: Wow, it worked.
I don't know how to really thank you. Thank you very much my friend.
But where exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is a visibility towards your controllers and repos , so scanning your application and it's components requires a that they should be set to their correct place